# Viewport and Render Image not matching

Tags: modeling, rendering, rigging, 3d-view, bones

Help please, I've been trying to figure out a fix to this problem for hours now but can't seem to find it.

Every time I render this project, it doesn't seem to match the final render from the viewport. I've tried clicking stuff but cant find anything.

If you know a fix to Viewport and render not matching please let me know
I have a 2070, Ryzen 5 3600, I'm fairly new to blender, my current project is a modelling project with rigs, and it's the second project now where I get this issue.[image]

As you can see in the picture, the hand on the render is different then on the viewport.

Comment: difficult to say for sure without the blend file. could be conditional modifiers, could be animation action, might even be different objects - one for viewport and one for render.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Quickly tho could you possibly tell me some places where I should check for a fix? Because I have no clue where to look anymore /:

Comment: Update: I deleted everything on the non linear animation panel and it fixed it